# Sort articles by template variable

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have built a website (with MODX) where some products are managed and displayed via the articles addon. The products should have a custom ordering but I don't know how to use a template variable for that.
If I enter the name of the TV in the "Sort Field" field nothing is shown at all.

So is it somehow possible to use a TV there?
Or is there another way to achive a custom ordering (note that I need the summary and date fields, so I cant't abuse them for that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using getResource package. Look at sorbyTV, sortdirTV, sortbyTVType parameters in manual:

http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources#getResources-SelectionProperties